# Allowing the user to create a tableViewCell with text from another viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm creating an app, in which one of the functions is, that the user should be able to write a person's name and an answer to a question - and then when pressing the **save-button** he/she should be redirected to the previous controller again, which not have created a `tableViewCell` with this data as title. (Later on you can ofcourse click this cell and see the data in third viewcontroller.)

My way of tackling this was to let the "**save**" button save the name and the answer by using `NSUserDefault`. Then connecting a `segue` to the button at the same time to make it redirect the user to the previous controller - and finally to have the tableView in the previous controller refer to the newly created `NSUserDefault-key` in the cell.textfield.

I have two questions.

> 1. Why does this not work? My code from both viewControllers are underneeth. I don't get why it doesn't work.
> 2. If I do get this to work: How do I implement the effect, that every time you enter the "Creating viewController", in which you can write the name and the answer - the user gets the option of saving a NEW person and adding a NEW cell, instead of overriding the old one, which I'm afraid will happen if I get the current approach to work...

Code in the "**Creating viewController**", where you can write the name and the answer:

```
class CreateNewPerson: UIViewController {
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

@IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ExtraIdentifier: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var PersonName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var PersonAnswer: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var PersonExtraIdentifier: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
showDiaryIdentifiers () }

func showDiaryIdentifiers () {
    let DiaryQuestion = self.defaults.string(forKey: "DiaryQuestionKey")
    let ExtraIdentifer = self.defaults.string(forKey: "RandomIdentifierKey")

    self.Question.text = DiaryQuestion
    self.ExtraIdentifier.text = ExtraIdentifer
}

@IBAction func SavePerson () {
self.defaults.setValue(self.PersonName.text, forKey: "PersonNameKey")
self.defaults.setValue(self.PersonAnswer.text, forKey: "PersonAnswerKey")
self.defaults.setValue(self.PersonExtraIdentifier.text, forKey: "PersonExtraIdentiferKey")
} }
```

**Code in the other viewController:**

```
 class AllPersonsInYourDiary: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

@IBOutlet weak var ShowingDiaryName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ShowingDiaryQuestion: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ShowingExtraIdentifer: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    showDiaryIdentifiers()
    
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func showDiaryIdentifiers () {
    let DiaryName = self.defaults.string(forKey: "DiaryNameKey")
    let DiaryQuestion = self.defaults.string(forKey: "DiaryQuestionKey")
    let ExtraIdentifer = self.defaults.string(forKey: "RandomIdentifierKey")
    
    self.ShowingDiaryName.text = DiaryName
    self.ShowingDiaryQuestion.text = DiaryQuestion
    self.ShowingExtraIdentifer.text = ExtraIdentifer
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Person1", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.defaults.string(forKey: "PersonNameKey")
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)

    return cell
}
```

In this code, I guess what is not working is the `cellForRowAt` method. What am I getting wrong? Right now it's not creating any cells at all.

Also, I know I should notr1 return 1 row and 1 section. It's just for now. I know I should in the end return Something.count - but I haven't yet figured out what this something is...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You already created a table view with only one row.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

When returning to previous controller just reload tableview like(Make sure before reloading datasource have contain new data.)

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you need the user to enter a set of values and then use these values to populate a table view in another view controller, then what you wanna do is:
1- create 2 dictionaries, an optional dictionary in `AllPersonsInYourDiary` that would carry the new values and one in your `CreateNewPerson` something like this `let dic = [[String: String]]()`.

2- Instantiate the view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "#yourSegueIdentifier" {
      let vc = segue.destination as! AllPersonsInYourDiary
      vc.dic = self.dic
    }
}
```

3- in your `AllPersonsInYourDiary` view controller, override the functions like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return dic.count
  }
```

and populate the cell

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Person1", for: indexPath)

     cell.textLabel?.text = dic[indexPath.row]["#whateverKeyForValue"]
     cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
     cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)

     return cell
 }
```

Comment: It seems right, what you are trying to make me do here. However I'm having some issues creating the two dictionaries correctly. It keeps telling me "Expected member name or constructor call after type name". I haven't worked a lot with dictionaries, so can you help me with creating these in the right way?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the braces for instantiation :)
```let dic = [[String:String]]()```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works. But how do I pass the NSUserDefault-values into these dictionaries? Is it code that I need to add to the SavePerson-button, so that the vallues/keys are directly saved into the new dictionary? - Or is it something that I must write in the dictionary itself?

Comment: Your don't need user defaults at all now. It's impractical.
All you have to do is save the values from the input fields to the dictionary directly, and when the segue is started, you pass the dictionary with all its values to the next view controller and populate the fields with it. 
So it's something like this: ```dic[0]["name"] = self.someInputField?.text```

Comment: But if I get that to work, will the cells stay then? When leaving the viewController or even the app? Because that was the reason I was using UserDefault in the first place

Comment: And also: What do you mean by your "WhatEverKeyForValue", if it is now refering to the UserDefault key?

Comment: Right now, when I just erase the UserDefaults and try to save the values directly to the dictionary, I get: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: the dictionary stores values based on keys.. just like user defaults, which map to a dictionary BTW. I suggest you read more about dictionaries, they're very helpful.

Comment: They will stay if you repopulate the values in ViewDidLoad() func. 
If you want them to stay forever, then you should consider CoreData.. which is a framework by Apple that stores your values in a Data Base.

Comment: For the error that you get, could you share the code snippet and the error log?